# Capturing the output from COM port using PowerShell on Windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, port, powershell-2.0

I want to send Sierra AT commands to a COM port and capture the output and store it in a variable using PowerShell.

PowerShell version:

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : eb5987f0-9961-4842-b349-ba215d86fdfa
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserI
                   nterface
CurrentCulture   : en-IN
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

For example:
`at!gstatus?`

I tried this, but it's not working for me.

```
PS> [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
COM16
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM16,115200,None,8,one
PS> $port.open()
PS> $port.WriteLine("at!gstatus?")
PS> $port.WriteLine("`r")
PS> $port.ReadExisting() //getting null output
PS> $port.close()
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

*Modem ? COM port ? AT commands ? Is it 2015 or 1995 ? ^_^*

Try with a pause before reading the data:

```
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM16,115200,None,8,one
$port.Open()

$port.WriteLine( "at!gstatus?" + "`r" )
Start-Sleep -m 50

$port.ReadExisting()
$port.Close()
```

Source : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2980f24e-56d1-431f-aedc-811c087b5184/powershell-serial-com-port?forum=ITCG

Comment: Are you sure all the options (`COM16,115200,None,8,one`) are needed and correct ? Did you try other (simple) commands ? Did you try to wait more than 50ms ?

Comment: yeah the options are correct. what u mean by simple commands? Can you provide it? I waited for more than 50ms.

Comment: I mean other AT commands that work with your hardware. What is your modem ?

Comment: i tried other commands also. What i could see is, when i am sending the command, it is actually sending and i could see the command output after closing the port and opening it manually. The thing is i am not getting the buffer ouput. Do i need to wait more? or something else has to be done? I am using sierra wireless WWAN modem

Comment: Any success with this script ? http://supportishere.com/powershell-script-to-query-wireless-modem-and-pull-asset-information/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97617/discussion-between-saran-and-sodawillow).